# Old as this Earth horizontal wp menu issue :)

Tags: wordpress, menu

problem seen here
http://soloveich.com/

Trying to make the whole menu horizontal, but home link keeps running away

```
            <div id="navmenu">
<ul>
</li><a href="<?php echo get_settings('home'); ?>">Home</a></li>
<li><?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'main-menu' ) ); ?></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

and the css

```
#navmenu ul {margin: 0; padding: 0; 
list-style-type: none; list-style-image: none; float: right; }
#navmenu li {display: inline; padding: 5px 5px 35px 5px}
#navmenu a {text-decoration:none; color: white; }
#navmenu a:hover {color: purple; }
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You have `<ul></li>...`. That's not legal html. You cannot close a tag that's not been opened yet. That makes your home link be rendered OUTSIDE of the `<ul>`, because it's not properly contained within a `<li>...</li>` pair.

Comment: that's a typo :) the home link is still on top of the rest of the menu, when </li> fixed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The wordpress wp_nav_menu items is outputting a DIV and UL inside where you are placing it. The output is going to be:

```
<ul>
   <li>Home</li>
   <li>
        <!-- call to wp_nav_menu -->
           <div>
               <ul>
                 <li>...</li>
               </ul>
           </div>
        <!-- end wp_nav_menu -->
   </li>
</ul>
```

The child DIV and UL is display block and causing it to go to another line.

Your best bet would be to add the home link either inside the wordpress menu in the admin interface, or to the beginning of the ul through the wp_nav_menu function:

```
<?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'main-menu', 'items_wrap' => '<ul><li id="item-id"><a href="' . get_settings('home') . '">Home</a></li>%3$s</ul>' ) ); ?>
```

See the codex for more info:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu